# Is there a way to compare multiple rows in one column in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've been using SQL for just over 25 years, but I'm relatively new to Oracle. My previous experience has been in DB2, and SQL Server.

I was asked to write a script that will look through a table with the following layout:

> OrderNo     int 
>   ClientID    varchar(20)
>   Order_Date  datetime
>   ProductCode varchar(5)
>   CreditLimit money
>   AccountNo   varchar(25)

The users enter the client's CreditAccountNo on every order. (I know it should be pulled from a table, but it's a homegrown application, and they didn't write it that way. Someday, I'll get them to let me fix that.)

The problem is that, while some clients do have more than one credit account, most only have one. But the users often mistakenly enter the wrong account no. They want me to write a script that looks at each clientid, and display the clients who have multiple account numbers in the table.

Normally, I would have something like this (pseudocode):

```
ClientID Cursor
    Read distinct ClientID
    Order Cursor
        Read Order Record for ClientID
        If first iteration, set variable X = AccountNo
        If AccountNo <> X print ClientID, X, AccountNo
        Read next row
    Loop
    Read next row
Loop
```

I'm wondering if there isn't a PL/SQL command to let me do away with the second loop.

Hopefully, this question makes sense.

Comment: Just curios about your approach here. Why do want a PL/SQL block, when  SQL can do this much more efficiently?

Comment: PL/SQL is the tool they have. Everything they have is written in PL/SQL. Still, I doubt they would know the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not this?

```
SELECT distinct client_id, accountNo
FROM (
SELECT client_id, 
       accountNo, 
       count(distinct accountNo) 
            over ( partition by client_id) client_account_count
FROM your_table
) 
where client_account_count > 1;
```

### Update

Added number of rows for each account number, as suggested in comments by Justin Cave. This helps one distinguish the account numbers that are probably correct from those that are probably mistakes.

```
SELECT distinct client_id, accountNo, cnt
FROM (
SELECT client_id, accountNo, 
count(distinct accountNo) over ( partition by client_id) client_account_count, 
count(*) over ( partition by client_id, accountNo) cnt
FROM your_table
) 
where client_account_count > 1;
```

Comment: I'd tend to add a `count(*) over (partition by client_id)` to the mix so that you can see how common each of the `accountNo` values are.  Presumably, the most common account number will be the right one.

Comment: Nice addition, Justin.  I'm relatively new to Stack Overflow.  Would it be correct protocol for me to edit my answer and add that?  Thanks!

Comment: Yup!  That would be perfect.  Generally, people comment on good answers to suggest things they'd like to see added or tweaked to make the answer even better.

Comment: This is probably the answer, but I just found out my CPU_PER_CALL is set at a ridiculously low number, and there are ~16M records on the table, so I'm hitting my limit before I get anything back. The DBA is gone for the weekend, so I'll have to hit him up for a more realistic value.

Comment: Just curious if using `distinct` will have an impact the performance ? I believe so - Since Kevin just mentioned ~16M records. @JustinCave

Comment: @MahendarMahi - Well, it certainly won't help.  It's one more operation that has to be done.

Comment: Taking it out might help, but not enough to let me run the code.

Comment: This was the answer. Amusingly enough, I still can't run it, but the DBA can. So, they gave the assignment to him. He did point out that I provided him with the code, and I gave main credit to Matthew, and Justin. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 2):

PL/SQL and cursors are not required.  Straight-forward SQL with a `GROUP BY` + `HAVING` will get you the information you need.

```
SELECT ClientID, COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ClientID, AccountNo
          FROM OrderTable)
 GROUP BY ClientID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: It looks like he wanted the account numbers too.

Comment: @Matthew: I don't see that in his question, but then again, if that's what he really wants, your answer will work great :)  **EDIT**: Ah: I see it now in his pseudo code. Thanks for pointing that out.